# Built-in camera not working Ubuntu 12.04 + Lenovo Ideapad Y400

Tags: 12.04, webcam, lenovo

I have problems with my built-in camera, I've been looking at. It doesn't work with cheese nor any other programs and it worked fine with windows. The programs recognize the cam as Lenovo EasyCam but they are not able to use it. I think it's the Acer device of the lsusb output. Any ideas?

`j@j:~$ ls /dev/video*`
`/dev/video0`
`j@j:~$ lsusb`
`Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`
`Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`
`Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`
`Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub`
`Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub`
`Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub`
`Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp.`
`Bus 004 Device 002: ID 5986:0525 Acer, Inc`

Thank you!!!

Comment: i have the same problem.
but i found **it does works in AMSN**.
i also found that AMSN detect the camera as " /dev/video0:0 ".
I tried to change that setting in other program but no success... maybe it can help someone finding out what's wrong about it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried installing cheese and also guvcview and my built-in webcam still didn't work.  I have a DELL Vostro with Ubuntu 12.04.

Finally I went to System Settings and in the Hardware section opened Additional Drivers.  The system found a driver for my AMD / Radeon video card.  I installed the driver and rebooted.  I tested the webcam with Kamerka and it worked!

Kamerka is a video app available in Ubuntu Software Center